# Multiple insert data to database using ASP.NET web form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to insert multiple data to database by code like this :

```
protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0;
            gvHitung.DataBind();
            int Loop = gvHitung.Rows.Count;
            while (i < Loop)
            {
                DataView dv = (DataView)sdsHitung.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
                DataRowView drv = dv[i];
                string Kd_Modul = drv["Kd_Modul"].ToString();
                sdsDataNilai.InsertParameters.Add("Binusian_Id",tbBinId.Text);
                sdsDataNilai.InsertParameters.Add("Kd_Jurusan",tbKdJur.Text);
                sdsDataNilai.InsertParameters.Add("Angkatan",tbAngkatan.Text);
                sdsDataNilai.InsertParameters.Add("Kd_Modul",Kd_Modul);
                sdsDataNilai.Insert();
                i++;
            }
            gvDataNilai.DataBind();
        }
```

but finally got error message

> "The variable name '@Binusian_Id' has already been declared. Variable
>   names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure."

when I redebug the program, I just saw I record saved. do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in every iteration in your `while` statement, you try add these parameters one by one again.

It is ok in the first iteration because it doesn't have any parameter at the begining. But in second iteration, your command already has these parameters. That's why you get error like;

> *Hey buddy, your command has already have a parameter called @Binusian_Id, why do you want to add the same parameter again?*

You need clear your parameters with [`SqlParameterCollection.Clear` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) before you add them again like;

```
sdsDataNilai.InsertParameters.Clear();
sdsDataNilai.InsertParameters.Add("Binusian_Id",tbBinId.Text);
sdsDataNilai.InsertParameters.Add("Kd_Jurusan",tbKdJur.Text);
sdsDataNilai.InsertParameters.Add("Angkatan",tbAngkatan.Text);
sdsDataNilai.InsertParameters.Add("Kd_Modul",Kd_Modul);
```